# D3 Transitions between classes

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I'm struggling with building a transition for the text fields in my force. Typing in the `.style` manually is no problem. The problem I face is when trying to use a css class to define my styles, and transition between them. Using `classed` does work but the problem is no smooth transition is done.

The flow I want is: 
 - mouseover --> add .highlighted class using a transition
 - mouseout --> remove .highlighted using a transition

The following works but not using transitions

```
text.highlighted {
   font-weight : bold;
}
```

JavaScript code:
//text is variable pointed to a selection

```
function mouseover() {
   text.classed("highlighted", true).transition().duration(1000) 
}

function mouseover() {
   text.classed("highlighted", false).transition().duration(1000) 
}
```

Reversing classed and transition doesn't work because classed works on a selection and return a selection. It seems like a trivial problem but I can't seem to make it work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're going to use classes, you'll need to define your transitions in CSS instead of D3.

Comment: This implementation feels woefully lacking, despite obvious complexities of building internal process to handle browser compatibility.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll need to define the transitions in CSS instead of D3. Vendor prefixes omitted from the following

```
text {
    font-weight: normal;
    transition: font-weight 1000ms;
}
text.highlighted {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Then, just set the class in D3:

```
function mouseover() {
   text.classed("highlighted", true); 
}

function mouseover() {
   text.classed("highlighted", false); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks this idea I didn't think of for some reason. +1